# React navigation reset first pops and then navigates

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using react navigation in my app, and when i am using reset for clearing the stack and navigating to other screen , it is showing weird animation,  like first all the screens that were in stack are poped and then it navigates to the new screen.

Here is the code

//code for resetting the stack

Login.js

```
   const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Home'})
        ],
    })
   this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

Route.js

```
Home: {
    screen: Tab,
    navigationOptions: {
        ...headerStyle,
    }
},
Intro: {
    screen: IntroScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        header: null
    }
},
LogIn: {
    screen: LogIn,
    navigationOptions: {
        ...headerStyle,
        title: 'LogIn',
    }
},
```

So it first goes to into screen and then to home screen, how to fix this so it directly goes to Home screen

Answer (score 0):

If you remove

```
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Home'})
        ],
    })
   this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

from your Login.js then the stack navigator automatically goes to the first screen in the StackNavigator , which in this case will be your `Home: {...}` screen.

There is no need for you to reset the stack.

If you want to navigate to another screen by pressing a button for example then use

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
export default class Initial extends Component {

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>

          <Button
            onPress={() => navigate('Login')}
            title="Go to Login"
            color="#357DED"
          />

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to clear the stack also ..about code snippet will add login to backstack